# Comparing elements between two user inputted arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, twitter

(I'm fairly new to programming...be gentle :C)
I'm trying to complete an Extra credit assignment in which I have to code a twitter scanner. I have to first take user input into a hashtag
ex: "#CMSC101"
and then read "tweets' from the user until the user enters '.'
from there the program counts how many times the user used the hashtag and how many times the hashtag was mention in the tweets

progress:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

int [MAX_TWEET_SIZE];
char target_tweet[MAX_TWEET_SIZE];
char tweet = 0;
int match = 0;
int instance = 0;

printf ("Enter Target Tweet\n");

fgets (target_tweet, MAX_TWEET_SIZE, stdin);

if (target_tweet[0] != '#'){
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return 0;
}   

printf("Enter Tweets!\nenter '.' to quit: \n");


while (tweet < 140){
    scanf("%c", &tweet);
    tweet = tweet + 1;
    if ((tweet = target_tweet)){
        printf ("Tweet Matched.\n");
        match = match + 1;

    }
    if ((tweet = '.')){
        printf("%d tweet(s) matched\n", match); 
        return 0;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far and It's got some issues in it(ie: the while loop). I've gotten pretty discouraged and I am not sure if I am doing it right at all
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have some spelling errors, which may or may not be the source of the errors.

Comment: The Spelling errors weren't on my compiler however I'm glad you pointed them out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have some spelling errors. The first one is the printf in the while loop. The second is the int MAX_TWEET_SIZE at the top. You have an extra bracket.

Second of all in while `(tweet < 140){`, comparison is always true due to limited range of data type. I would recommend you to instead use `while(true){}`

The last error is with the `if ((tweet = target_tweet)){`. In this code, you are having a invalid conversion from `char*` to `char`. To fix this you can use `strcmp`, since you cannot compare two strings with "=". This is all I have found wrong with this code. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes at first glance:

```
if ((tweet = target_tweet))
```

In if cases you should use == if you want to check whether two variables are equal, but you cant compare two strings with it. You code would assign target_tweet to tweet but they're not even the same type. I don't even get what you want to do here. If you want to check whether tweet and target_tweet are equal, you should use strcmp and you should read in tweet as a string.

```
while (tweet < 140)
```

I dont see the need of this. you should simply use an infinite loop like:

```
while(1)
```

Basically I'd try it somehow like this:

```
while (1){
   scanf("%s", tweet);
   if (strcmp(tweet, target_tweet == 0){
       pritnf ("Tweet Matched.\n");
       match++;
   }

   if ((tweet[0] == '.')){
       printf("%d tweet(s) matched\n", match); 
      break; //to end the loop
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help there, I'm still unsure of how to write the strcomp function to make it return to the main function(if at all) the main issue im having is having the program do this:

target: #help

tweets: 

COMP SCI #help

Extra credit #help

Then the program says "tweet matched twice" from just similar elements from each string.